# how can i displaying a specific error in Joi?

Tags: joi

just a quick question I am suing Joi for validation and i wanna display a given error

```
 departureDate: Joi.date().format('YYYY-MM-DD').error(() => ({
  message: 'Date format must be YYYY-MM-DD'
})).min(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
  .required()
  .error(() => ({
    message: 'No trips to the past'
  })),
```

and the problem is that it's just displaying the last message even if I would put in a date format which is not correct

Comment: which verison of joi are you using?

Comment: "joi": "^14.3.1",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that is what the desirted behavior is. When you specify the custom error message it takes the last one. You can read more [here](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyerrorerr).

The better solution is to upgrade your hapi and use `.message` or with existing version use `.label`